how to create a class that has a default attribute
I would like to create a class such that when you use an instance of the class with out specifying an attribute name with .attribute_name, it will return the value from a "default" attribute.
The answer might just be to subclass the built in int or str type. But I don't want all the other methods that are available to these types, for example adding 2 instances of the class with the +. I know how to do this... just define a __new__() method for the subclass...
I do want to be able to create a list of instances of the class and be able to pass the list to various functions that take an iterable as a parameter, for example: the built in sum() or itertools's combinations(). But I also want to be able to declare additional attributes on the instances as well.
with int you can create a instance of it with i = int(17) and a list of ints with a = [int(17), int(11), int(21)]. And I can access the "default attribute" just by using the name of the variable and not variable_name.attribute_name. That is I can use i versus i.value in an expression.
for example I can do:
i = 28
print(i)            # outputs 28 (here I have no .attribute_name)
print(i.numerator)  # outputs 28 (numerator is an attribute of the variable i)

a = [17, 11, 21]
print(a[0])            # outputs 17 (again no .attribute_name)
print(a[0].numerator)  # outputs 17 (numerator is an attribute)
print(sum(a))          # outputs 49 (sum iterates over each item in the list `a`
                       #  I do not have to specify the attribute name that sum should 
                       #  to compute its results

something like...
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, x, y, value):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.value = value    # this should be the default attribute

i = Cell(5, 3, 17)
print(i)  # outputs 17
# the next line outputs: the point (5, 3) has the value of 17
print(f"the point ({i.x}, {i.y}) has a value of {i}"

s = Cell(7, 9, "red")
print(s)        # outputs red
print(len(s))   # outputs 3
print(s.x, s.y) # outputs 7 9

intarr = [Cell(1, 2, 17), Cell(3, 4, 11), Cell(5, 6, 21)]
print(intarr[0])                # outputs 17
print(intarr[0].x, intarr[0].y) # outputs 1 2
print(sum(intarr))              # outputs 49

from itertools import combinations
strarr = [Cell(1, 2, "bob"), Cell(3, 4, "joe"), Cell(5, 6, "ted")]
print(strarr[0])                # outputs bob
print(len(strarr[0]))           # outputs 3
print(strarr[0].x, strarr[0].y) # outputs 1, 2
# outputs: [('bob', 'joe'), ('bob', 'ted'), ('joe', 'ted')]
print(list(combinations(strarr, 2)))

# without this default attribute I have to write clunky code like:
print(sum(cell.value for cell in intarr))
print(list(combinations((cell.value for cell in strarr), 2)))

any help would be much appreciated

This isn't really how classes work in Python AFAIK. You might be looking for magic methods.

There is no "default attribute" for an int. When you look at an int and get an int, that's not because you're implicitly accessing some "default attribute" that's an int. It's because the object is an int.

The "default value" of an object is the object itself. If your object isn't an int, then it can't have an int as its "default value". However, you can make your object behave like an int by implementing specific methods: __str__ and __repr__ control what it looks like when you print it, so you could make it look like an int there. By implementing __add__ and similar methods, you can make it behave like an int in + operations etc. (I'm using an int as example here, but you can make it look and behave like anything else.)

You can make all your test cases pass by implementing __str__, __repr__, __add__ and __len__. In your combinations case you will get [(Cell(...), Cell(...)), ...] as result though, there's no way to pipe in a Cell and receive a str as output (even if you can make it look as such using __repr__).

I don't see a way without using a custom Cell class and redefining the relevant magic methods.
Here is an example that suits your requirements:
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, x, y, value):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.value = value

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Cell):
            # be able to work with other Cell objects AND built-ins
            other = other.value
        return self.value + other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        # built-in sum function will first make an __radd__ between self and int(0)
        if isinstance(other, Cell):
            other = other.value
        return self.value + other

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Cell({self.x}, {self.y}, {self.value})"

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.value)

And here is the main to test requirements:
from itertools import combinations


def main():
    test_cell_int()
    test_cell_str()


def test_cell_int():
    intarr = [Cell(1, 2, 17), Cell(3, 4, 11), Cell(5, 6, 21)]
    assert intarr[0] == 17
    assert (intarr[0].x, intarr[0].y) == (1, 2)
    assert sum(intarr) == 49


def test_cell_str():
    strarr = [Cell(1, 2, "bob"), Cell(3, 4, "joe"), Cell(5, 6, "ted")]

    assert strarr[0] == "bob"
    assert len(strarr[0]) == 3
    assert (strarr[0].x, strarr[0].y) == (1, 2)
    assert list(combinations(strarr, 2)) == [
        ("bob", "joe"),
        ("bob", "ted"),
        ("joe", "ted"),
    ]
    # The combinations will actually makes a tuple of the Cell objects, but the equality
    # check will work as expected because the __eq__ method is defined to compare the
    # value of the Cell objects
    print(list(combinations(strarr, 2)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


thanks for the detailed answer, with regards to sum the __radd__ method was exactly was needed... and sorry for my persistence here, but because many of the primitive types have similar behavior, I'm wondering if "this behavior" is being implemented via a meta class, or descriptor -- of which I know nothing about either...


with int you can create a instance of it with i = int(17) and a list of ints with a = [int(17), int(11), int(21)]. And I can access the "default attribute" just by using the name of the variable and not variable_name.attribute_name. That is I can use i versus i.value in an expression.

An int behaves like an int because the int class implements behaviour that makes it behave like an int.
int(17) is superfluous. It's the same as just 17. Because it's such a fundamental value, and because you need to be able to express it somehow, the int class basically has a special shortcut syntax in the language that allows you to write just 17 to obtain an instance of the class int with the value 17.
When printing such an instance, it displays as "17" because the int class implements __str__ and/or __repr__ to display this value as visible output.
When adding two ints together, it works because the int class implements __add__ and related methods to define addition behaviour.
(Since ints are implemented somewhere deeply in C, it probably actually bypasses the dunder-method implementations for more optimised ways to do the same thing; but in userland implementation, that would be how it works.)
In no case are print or + accessing some sort of "default attribute" of an int instance. In Python, the class defines the behaviour. It's not that Python defines how int addition works and needs to get some primitive int out of an int instance to do the addition. No, an int instance is the value and the int class defines how it'll behave when added to something else.
What you want is just that: add behaviour to your class by implementing the appropriate dunder methods. In your case, something along the lines of:
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, x, y, value):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(str(self))

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value + other.value

    def __len__(self):
        return 3  # or however you determine that

This even passes this case:
# outputs: [('bob', 'joe'), ('bob', 'ted'), ('joe', 'ted')]
print(list(combinations(a, 2)))

But, it'll only look like 'bob' due to __repr__, in actuality you'll still have Cell instances. Because it makes no sense to pass Cell instances to combinations but gets strings out. If there was some "default attribute" mechanism, how is Python to decide when you want your instance as is and when you want its "value". That's just not how that works.

thanks for your very detailed answer. After experimenting a bit, I found that adding the __radd__ method to my Cell class, specifically, was enough to get the sum of a list of Cell objets working. where 'raddreturnedself.value + other... but then I stated wondering what **attribute** does int's add&raddmethods use to compute the addition with other? After all anint` is just an object and as you stated, there is no "default attribute"... or any other of the primitive types (float, string, etc.)? Could it be something like a meta class?

sorry for being persistent here, I guess I'm just a little skeptical when I see phrases like "probably..." in the answer. Additionally, with regards to int(17) being the same as 17 or  float(1.7) is the same as 1.7, I tend to think its not simply "special shortcut syntax" as there would have to be shortcuts for each primitive type, so why not make it a language feature... (via meta classes or ???) if we used the dis module, could we see if the python compiler parses 17 into the same bytecode that is produced using int(17)?

Again, ints are a very fundamental type implemented in C and don’t need to follow the same rules you’d have in userland code.

final comment... I guess I was hoping for something similar to the __call__ dunder method, where you can write my_class_instance() and have it call the __call__ method implemented for the class. and writing my_class_instance would return an attribute that was somehow marked as the instance's "value". that's why I asked about meta classes. I guess I should have made my original question "is there some advanced python language feature that will enable an instance of a class to return a primitive value without using dot-attribute notation" but then people would ask for an example :-p

There aren’t many more ways to tell you this: no, there isn’t.

To accommodate strings, and returning value: __repr__
To accommodate sum-s: __add__, __radd__
class Cell:
    def __init__(self, x, y, value):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

    def __radd__(self, value2):
        if isinstance(value2, Cell):
            value2 = value2.value
        return Cell(
            x=self.x,
            y=self.y,
            value=self.value+value2,
        )

    def __add__(self, value2):
        return self.__radd__(value2)

Indeed if you would like to go for more specific value type you should subclass that type instead.

This customizes what an object looks like, which isn't what the questioner is trying to do.

I mean it covers all the use cases OP asked about. So we leverage "looks" to handle generic subclassing. A notch hacky, like any python-ish "generic type" scenario.

This does not cover all the use cases the questioner asked about. print(sum(intarr)) will fail.

right, so would this: sum(["a", 1, 2]), OP didn't want to define further class methods like __add__

They specifically wrote print(sum(intarr)) in the test cases as an example of something that should work.

it will work if only int are provided as arguments. It requires way more nuance in order to define how should sum of generic types look like. Also it all would be covered under __add__ magic method - which OP didn't want to do.

ints were provided as arguments in that test case. Your code fails on the given test cases, and does not properly answer the question.

good point - I focused on making str part work - see now it will do the trick (still summing is per the best attempt at stated objective, which isn't crystal clear for summing).

You could redefine the __radd__ method to make the sum function work without giving Cell(0, 0, 0) as initial value to sum.

I'm sorry. As I directly edited, I didn't check the output. With def __call__, the returned object can be used in later function but can't be printed as output. So, Using __str__ allows you to set a default function to the class. As you have to use the output in the later part of the code I used call method, because with __str__ method, you can output only  str.(deleted my previous answer with __call__ method)
class Cell:
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, value):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.value = value 

    def __str__(self):
        
        return str(self.value)

    def another_function(self):
        # function with self.x, self.y, self.z

print(Cell(17,4,3)) # output : 3

print(cell(17, 11, 21).another_function())
# Output: another value returned from another_function

